# Copy large number of rows, prevent users create or update new record during the process

Tags: mysql

I am writing a multilingual CMS where admin can add and delete languages. When they add a new language, I would copy all the rows from multiple table with language_id = 1 and insert them with the newly created language_id .

I'm using PHP so the database copying and inserting process would probably be done asynchronously. The problem is the user might add new content during the process and there is a chance both language would not have the same number of rows in the end.

I could probably lock all the table involved but since the user of the CMS is not tech savvy, I don't want them to see a generic error message when they try to create or update record.

I would much prefer to show them a customize message notifying them the system is converting language. But doing so require me to know that tables are being locked.

I should add that CRUD are mostly done by one person at any time so there should be less difficulties.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: You can give the user your own error message you know. In fact most systems lock themself for such a serious update and just display a message that you can't do anything until it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I would just lock the table where new rows are inserted while doing the "creating new language" operation. That way any new insert would automatic wait until the "creating new language" operation was finished, and all the user would see was a slight delay.

This is assuming that the "creating new language" can be done i a few seconds but I can't imagine this being a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by ***I should add that CRUD are mostly done by one person at any time so there should be less difficulties**.*? if your assumption is correct, how in the world developers are making concurrent requests, same time ?

Generally you will only have one DAO (Data access object) and all your code will come to that which will make a single connection to database and it will be synchronized all the time. Did you follow this practice ? php asynchronous means while pinging the server, ajax request will be made. Not while communicating with DB. If there are so many clients connecting, there will be a pattern of connection pooling. Think of it, does this make any sense ?